# Update two cells in one raw in Gridview using EditableColumn

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, kartik-v

I have an editable GridView in my Yii2 app and using kartik EditableColumn. When there was only one editable column everything works Ok but when I tried to add one more editable column it saves editted value of **Price** column and sets to zero the value of **expire_days** column. The same for opposite way(if update **expire_days** it saves the value but sets to zero the **Price** value).

The View:

```
'columns' => [
    [
        'class'=>'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute' => 'price',
        'editableOptions'=>[
            'header'=>' ',                         
            'inputType'=>\kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_SPIN,
            'options'=>['pluginOptions'=>['min'=>0, 'max'=>5000000]]
        ],
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return $model->price;
         },
        'filter' => Category::getPrices(),
        'format' => 'raw'
    ],


    [
        'class'=>'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute' => 'expire_days',
        'editableOptions'=>[
            'header'=>' ',
            'inputType'=>\kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_SPIN,
            'options'=>['pluginOptions'=>['min'=>0, 'max'=>100]]
         ],
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return $model->expire_days;
         },
        'filter' => Category::getExpDays(),
        'format' => 'raw'
    ],                                         
]
```

Controller:

```
if (Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')) {
    $model = new Category();
    $id = Yii::$app->request->post('editableKey');
    $model = Category::findOne($id);
    $out = Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'message'=>'']);

    $post = [];
    $posted = current($_POST['Category']);
    $post['Category'] = $posted;

    if ($model->load($post)) {
        $model->price = $post['Category']['price'];
        $model->expire_days = $post['Category']['expire_days'];
        $model->save();
        $output = '';
        $out = Json::encode(['output'=>$output,'message'=>'']);
    }

    echo $out;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separately process two scenarios:

```
if ($model->load($post)) {
    if ($post['Category'] && $post['Category']['price']) {
        $model->price = $post['Category']['price'];
    }

    if ($post['Category'] && $post['Category']['expire_days']) {
        $model->expire_days = $post['Category']['expire_days'];
    }
    $model->save();
    $output = '';
    $out = Json::encode(['output'=>$output,'message'=>'']);
}
```

If you receive price - you update only price. If you receive expire_days - update expire_days.

Comment: Thank's a lot, that fixed my problem:)! I tried to separate them but in another way